# rails, websockets and grunt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, websocket, gruntjs

I've added web socket functionality to my server, so when adding new item, it sends event to the client.
server side works like a charm, no issue here.

my problem is while running in development, the issue is that my server runs on port 7000, and my grunt serve on port 8000 and has proxy for 7000. but the proxy does not work both ways....what i mean is that if in angular i write

```
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails($location.host()+":"+$location.port()+"/websocket");
```

it does't work, as it listen to port 8000 and not 7000.
even if i add the configuration of the grunt proxy configuration

```
{context: '/websocket', host: 'myhost', port: '7000}
```

if I'm hard coding the port, e.g.

```
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails($location.host()+":7000/websocket");
```

it works without an issue...but i want the code to be dynamic.
I searched, but couldn't find, is there a way to configure a reverse proxy for grunt, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok....the solution was pretty simple....just hard to find.
i added to the proxy configuration mentioned above the following:

```
ws:true
```

so now it looks like this:

```
{context: '/websocket', host: 'myhost', port: '7000', ws:true}
```

and everything works great.